What is the Rust reqwest equivalent of the following Python requests code?
I am trying to do a Basic Authentication GET, ignoring certificate validation, using reqwests.
I have following Python requests code, which works:
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

session = requests.sessions.Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth("username", "password")
session.verify = False
response = session.get("http://myurl.com/myapi")

I want to do the same thing using Rust reqwest.
So far, I have the following:
use reqwest

let url = "http://myurl.com/myapi";

let response = reqwest::Client::builder()
  .danger_accept_invalid_certs(true)
  .build()
  .unwrap()
  .get(&url)
  .basic_auth("username", Some("password"))
  .send()
  .await?;

The Python requests call works as expected. However, I get the following response from Rust:
Error: reqwest::Error { kind: Request, url: Url { scheme: "https", cannot_be_a_base: false, username: "", password: None, host: Some(Domain("myurl.com")), port: None, path: "myapi", query: None, fragment: None }, source: Error { kind: Connect, source: Some("unsuccessful tunnel") } }

If I need to produce more code (I can't provide the actual URL), please let me know.

Aside from verifying that you theoretically do have the correct username/password and permission to access the site, the Python code is irrelevant to the question (it doesn't help clarify the task, which is already perfectly obvious) and doesn't make this a Python question. I have removed the corresponding details.

I kindly disagree. I know the Python code works. Perhaps there is something that the Python code is doing correctly that my Rust code is missing. For instance, I am not sure what the equivalent of Session.verify: bool is in a Rust Request object. Or, for that matter, if it is something that reqwest implements, or even it is something that is taken care of in the Client.

Are you using proxy?

@user459872 - no proxies. Sadly, the Python code was removed in an edit.

@trozzel, please do not roll this back. The Python code is important.

I would hardly consider this an answer, but I will post this just to update my solution.

I first updated my Cargo.toml reqwest dependency to the following to remove TLS dependencies:
reqwest = version = "0.12.4", default-features = false }


this was causing reqwest to throw a TooManyRedirects error.
Removing the default-features also disables the ability to control redirects, so this didn't work.


Then, after resetting my Cargo.toml to:
reqwest = "0.12.4"


I updated the GET call, removing the .danger_accept_invalid_certs(true) line:
let response = reqwest::Client::builder()
  .danger_accept_invalid_certs(true)
  .build()
  .unwrap()
  .get(&url)
  .basic_auth("username", Some("password"))
  .send()
  .await?;



It's now working.
Again, I don't know if that's necessarily a problem / problem solved, but I'm posting it just in case.
